# Tradução do Matlab para R com system(sprintf())

Tags: r, matlab

Estou tentando traduzir o seguinte código de matlab para o R:

```
clear all
nsta = [1,2,3];
npx  = [2,3,4,5];
npu  = [2,3,4,5];
nmax = 2500;
nome = 'MODEL1b';
system(sprintf('del %s.log',nome));
nfiles = 0;
for k = 1:length(nsta)
    for i = 1:length(npx)
        for j = 1:length(npu)
            nx = nsta(k);
            npar = (npx(i)^nx)*npu(j);
            if (npar < nmax)
                nfiles = nfiles+1;
                system(sprintf('copy %s%d%d%d.txt  %s.txt',nome,nx,npx(i),npu(j),nome));
                system(sprintf('copy input%d%d%d.txt  input.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
                system(sprintf('copy template%d%d%d.txt template.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
                tic;
                system(sprintf('RFuzzy %s',nome));
                time = toc;
                fprintf('Arquivo: %d    Config: %d%d%d    Time: %f',nfiles,nx,npx(i),npu(j),toc);
                system(sprintf('copy min.txt min%d%d%d.txt',nx,npx(i),npu(j)));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
rm(list = ls())
nsta <- c(1,2,3)
npx <- c(2,3,4,5)
npu <- c(2,3,4,5)
nmax <- 2500
nome <- "MODEL1b"
system(sprintf('del %s.log', nome))
nfiles <- 0
for(k in 1:length(nsta)){
  for(i in 2:length(npx)){
    for(j in 2:length(npu)){
      nx <- nsta[k]
      npar <- (npx[i]^nx)*npu[j]
      if(npar < nmax){
        nfiles <- nfiles + 1
        system(sprintf('copy %s%d%d%d.txt  %s.txt',nome,nx,npx[i],npu[j],nome))
        system(sprintf('copy input%d%d%d.txt  input.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
        system(sprintf('copy template%d%d%d.txt template.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
        system(sprintf('RFuzzy %s',nome))
        fprintf('Arquivo: %d    Config: %d%d%d    Time: %f',nfiles,nx,npx[i],npu[j])
        system(sprintf('copy min.txt min%d%d%d.txt',nx,npx[i],npu[j]))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Já na sétima linha, aparece o erro:

```
Warning message:
running command 'del MODEL1b.log' had status 127
```

Como proceder?

Comment: Você está executando o R no Windows?

Comment: @Daniel , estou.

Comment: O diretório dos arquivos é o mesmo diretório que está sendo executado no script? Se necessário, use `setwd("c:/nome_do_diretório")`. Veja o padrão de referenciação do diretório no Windows. Assegure-se que este diretório não contém acento, poderia gerar algum problema.

Comment: @Daniel estou certificado de que os diretórios são os mesmos. Alguma ideia a mais?

Comment: O teu script está travando na primeira linha que exige iteração. O único problema associado é esse. Execute `system("dir")` e verifique se está recuperando o arquivo de log.

Comment: Pq não usar file.remove() e file.copy()?

Comment: @Rcoster como assim? Pode sugerir uma resposta?

Answer (score -1):

Tente:

```
rm(list = ls())
nsta <- c(1, 2, 3)
npx <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
npu <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
nmax <- 2500
nome <- "MODEL1b"
file.remove(sprintf('%s.log', nome))
nfiles <- 0

for(k in 1:length(nsta)){
     for(i in 2:length(npx)){
         for(j in 2:length(npu)){
         nx <- nsta[k]
         npar <- (npx[i]^nx)*npu[j]
         if(npar < nmax){
             nfiles <- nfiles + 1
             file.copy(from = sprintf('%s%d%d%d.txt', nome, nx, npx[i], npu[j]), to = sprintf('%s.txt', nome))
             file.copy(from = sprintf('input%d%d%d.txt', nx, npx[i], npu[j]), to = 'input.txt')
             file.copy(from = sprintf('template%d%d%d.txt', nx, npx[i], npu[j]), to = 'template.txt')
             system(sprintf('RFuzzy %s', nome)) # Provavelmente aqui vai dar erro. Mas pelo menos ganhamos algumas linhas :)
             cat(sprintf('Arquivo: %d Config: %d%d%d Time: %f', nfiles, nx, npx[i], npu[j])
             file.copy(from = 'min.txt', to = sprintf('min%d%d%d.txt', nx, npx[i], npu[j]))
             }
         }
     }
}
```